# Error al ejecutar generador de codigos asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

Entorno de desarrorllo Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Versión 16.8.2
Marcos de trabajo:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
Microsoft.NetCore.App

Cuando voy al explorador de soluciones, controllers boton derecho, agregar controlador y selecciono controlador ...
Controlador de MVC con vistas que usan Entity Framework
Después de intentar realizar el scaffold me lanza un error:
Error al ejecutar el código seleccionado "Could not load field or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx. El sistema no puede encotra el archivo especificado. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este error se me soluciono actualizando a la versión del proyecto a la 5(Actual) de ASP.NET Core al igual que las librerías porque el paquete Nuget que es el generador de interfaces no estaba en la misma versión, intenta realizando la actualización.

Comment: Hay que actualizar las dependencias a la ultima version disponible
por ejemplo si es netcore 3.1 actualizar todas las dependencias a la versio 3.1.17

Comment: A mi me funciono:
Clic derecho en el proyecto -> Limpiar Solución
y volver a compilar... ahí ya generó el Código

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Actualizar a la versión 5 del paquete Microsoft.Bcl.Asyncinterfaces version=1.0.0.0 por la misma pero versión 5.
2.Después me ha surgido otro error:

System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message = The database provider attempted to register an implementation of the 'IRelationalTypeMappingSource' service. This is not a service defined by Entity Framework and as such must be registered
------------------------------------------------------------------------

3.Lo que he me ha llevado a actualizar de la versión 3.1.4 a la 5 los siguientes paquetes:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Y dejando Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design(3.1.4). Y por ahora resuelto
```

Answer (score 0):

Un problema que me tuvo sin dormir 1 semana, desarrollo en netcore 3.1 + mysql, comencé con el proyecto en septiembre 2020, lo tenia en GitHub.

Lo tuve postergado y lo retome desde un nuevo PC en enero 2021 y me paso lo siguiente:

1. Al crear una nueva entidad no me dejaba realizar comando Update-Database, me daba error "update-database System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.".
2. Luego de corregir el problema anterior, no me dejaba utilizar el generador automático de Controller y View: "Controlador de MVC con vistas que usan Entity Framework", me daba error "error al ejecutar el generador de codigo".

Intente muchos "trucos" Microsoft, eliminar carpetas donde se guardan los paquetes, eliminar carpetas temporales, restaurar desde comando dotnet, cambiar de paquete Mysql a Pomelo, actualice algunos paquetes que indicaban en varios post. Nada funcionaba.

Finalmente, tome todos los paquetes en versión 3.1.9 y los actualice a 3.1.11. Magi-Microsoft-mente funciono.

Ojala a alguien le sirva, acá la lista de paquetes con su versión que me funciono:

Answer (score 0):

Trabajando con NetCore 3.1
[image: Actualización de dependencias]
Al actualizar todas las dependencias a la ultima versión.

Contaba con la versión 3.1.1 y actualicé a 3.1.20 solucionó el problema.